# Displaying default image when there is no image to display

Tags: php

I am having problem with displaying default image. I do not know where exactly to place it.

```php
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM adoption;");

if($result->num_rows !=NULL){
    while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $AAnimalName = $rows['AAnimalName'];
        $Abreed = $rows['Abreed'];
        $Asex = $rows['Asex'];
        $Acolor = $rows['Acolor'];
        $image = $rows ['image'];
        ?>
        <div class="container-custom1">
            <?php echo '<img src = "admin/function/upload/'.$image.'" width = "248" height="190" class="age1" title>'?>
            <?php echo "<i><h1 class='junction'><a style='cursor:pointer' class='junction'>".$AAnimalName."</a></h1></i>"."<br>".$Asex." /".$Abreed."<br>".$Acolor."<br>"?></div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this inside  `while` loop :

```
$image_location = "admin/function/upload/".$image;
if(file_exists($image_location )) {
    echo '<img src = "'.$image_location .'" width = "248" height="190" class="age1" title>';
}
else {
    echo '<img src = "admin/function/upload/default_image.jpg'" width = "248" height="190" class="age1" title>';
}
```

Comment: inside while loop?

Comment: after `<div class="container-custom1"><?php` this code

Comment: Made it. Thanks!! Some correction to your code. Thanks man!

>file_exist should be file_exists

Comment: I want to ask more. About my jquery tooltip. I want to show you something.

Comment: I thinks you submit again a question details about query tooltip. of course, i will help you or explain details here

Comment: I have these set of images and whenever i hover them, the track is set to true and will display information of each image. `$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.age1').tooltip({ content: '<img src="admin/function/upload/13624492_1220596404618619_886995775_n.jpg" width="250" height="250"/>',
   track:true}); 
    
});`

Comment: what is problem here?

Comment: the image that being displayed is the same for all in class `.age1`. I want every image shown will be their own image and info.

Comment: try this : `$(".age1").hover(function() {
  var imgScr = $(this).attr('src');
  $(this).tooltip({ 
   content: '<img src="'+imgScr+'" width="250" height="250"/>', 
   track:true
  }); 
 });`

Comment: RAZIB!! It worked. Finally!!!!! Btw, I am new to html css php and java. How can I give you a ton of +rep? So helpful. I need also to display the image information or link each for more info.

Comment: Life saver. Is there any way that i can contact you? You're so helpful man.

Comment: Done. How about adding links on each of the image linking to a new target to display image's info.

Comment: see my code and try to apply : `$(".age1").hover(function() {
  var imgScr = $(this).attr('src');
  
  var html = '';
  html += '<img src="'+imgScr+'" width="250" height="250"/>';
  html += '<h1>Images title</h1>';
  html += '<a href="">link</a>';
  
  $(this).tooltip({ 
   content: html, 
   track:true
  }); 
 });`

Comment: Will do after my class. Still on school. Trying to code. I'll update ya mate.

Comment: Razib, any other way to contact you?

Comment: I think there is bug. The tooltip shown stucks on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line like this:

```
<?php echo '<img onerror="this.src=\'img/logo.png\'" src = "admin/function/upload/'.$image.'" width = "248" height="190" class="age1" title>'?>
```

`img/logo.png` would be the default image

Comment: Okay let me try

Comment: @Powerballs , make sure the default path exist!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
If(file_exist('your_file_path'))
{
    echo '<img src = "admin/function/upload/'.$image.'" width = "248" height="190" class="age1" title>';
}
else
{
    echo '<img src = "admin/function/upload/default_image.jpg'" width = "248" height="190" class="age1" title>';
}
```

This will check if the file exist or not. If exist, it will display given file. Otherwise a default file.

Comment: inside while loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
  $image = (!empty($rows ['image'])) ? $rows ['image'] : "default.png" ;
```

Comment: could you please include an explanation in your answer, so future readers might understand *how* it works?

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator and set image

```
<?php

  $image = (!empty($rows ['image'])) ? $rows ['image'] : "default.png" ;
 $image_location = "admin/function/upload/".$image;
echo '<img src = "admin/function/upload/'.$image.'" width = "248" height="190"    class="age1" title>';

   ?>
```